# How to change the scope of a variable, defined inside a for-loop inside an if conditional, to use it outside?

Tags: c

```
if(condition)
{
     for(int i=10; i>=0 ; i--)
     {
         //Wanted to change the scope of the variable "i" 
     }
}
```

I want to change the scope of variable `i`;
so that it can be used outside the if statement.

Comment: Hint: you **do not** want to make `i` a global-variable in C. Avoid using global variables as much as possible.

Comment: Then define it outside the `if` statement? And give it some better name.

Comment: With that said, what is the problem you need to solve? After the loop `i` will always be equal to `-1`. So what is it to be used for?

Comment: Hi Muhammad. Your questions does not provide enough code to discuss the global scope, because that is not visible. The shown code is however sufficient to discuss changing the sope of `i` to just outside `if`. I did so in my answer (heeding comments above). I propose to change the question to either provide a [mre] for the global scope; or to make it discuss only extending scope sufficiently, i.e. to remove all reference to "global". If you like I will do the second option for you.

Comment: Just to point out some counter examples to the "don't use global variables" advice that I see so often: `Serial` in `Serial.print()` is a global variable. Also, all variables into and out of ISRs are global variables. Lastly, any outermost scope `static` variable in any C source file is a "file scoped" global variable, and is the C equivalent of private class member variables you'd use in C++. All these uses of globals I've mentioned are good uses and good examples for global variables.

Comment: @GabrielStaples You are free to provide a answer with global scope. I also like the file scope approach as a compromise. (For both however I expect you will need a better MRE  from OP...)

Comment: I agree with all of your suggestions. Actually, after reading the comments I realize that I don't want to make the variable global but I want to use its value outside "IF" statement.

Comment: I edited the question according to your new (reduced) goal. Feel free to fix anything I have broken. In that case please accept my apology.

Comment: You have fixed this buggy question. Thanks, Yunnosch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to make variable `i` useable outside of `if()` (without turning it into a global variable, i.e. heeding the recommendations in the comments, which I agree with).
Just define (and preferrably initialise) the variable before (i.e. outside) of `if()`. This makes whatever scope the `if()` is in the scope of the variable.
Just move the definition far enough outwards to make it useable where you want it.
Important is to then NOT define it inside the `if(){}` again, i.e. remove the original/second `int`, so that whatever you do inside stays visible outside.
With another definition within `if`, there would be a local variable shadowing the one you want to use.

```
int i=9; /* initialised, out of habit */
i++; // useable here, now 10, but your intended use might result in other values
if(condition)
{
     for(i=10; i>=0 ; i--) /* assign 10, to make sure */
     {
         // whatever 
     }
}
i++; // also useable here
```